# Wordpress custom post types current post

Tags: wordpress

What I have is a podcast page with multiple podcast. but when I click into a podcast, it takes me to the most recent podcast and not the one that I had clicked on. How do I get the current podcast and not the most current one that was uploaded? below is where I am calling the the post to the new single.php file that I have created. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
) );
?>

<?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="container mycontainer">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="whiteText col-md-12">hs</h1>

          <a href="<?php the_permalink($post); ?>"><h2 class="whiteText episodeTitle col-md-8"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
          <span class="whiteText col-md-12"><em>Hosted by</em></span>
        </div>

          <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the default loop with your own `WP_Query` which is set up to just return the most recent post of type `custom-post-type`.

Is there a reason you are not using the standard Wordpress loop? If you have everything set up properly, your single.php should show the correct post by default without having to re-query for it:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="container mycontainer">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="whiteText col-md-12">hs</h1>

          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2 class="whiteText episodeTitle col-md-8"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
          <span class="whiteText col-md-12"><em>Hosted by</em></span>
        </div>

          <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. that is also something that i realized :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `the_permalink()` as `$post` will return the ID of the main post outside of your loop.

Comment: hmm, I still seem to be pulling the incorrect post to the page.

Comment: This does work, thank you, I just need to delete $post in a few other places

Comment: @Semanm deleting the $post variable isn't enough... you also need to delete your custom WP_Query - that's totally unnecessary and also going to cause problems :-)